# custom form control which is a wrapper around an other control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Suppose you have a reactive custom form control component, lets say `app-foo`, which nicely implements the `ControlValueAccessor` and can be used in forms like

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <app-foo formControlName="importantStuff"></app-foo>
</form>
```

Now, I would like to wrap `app-foo` with a component which adds, for example, just a label

```
<label>Some label message</label>
<app-foo formControlName="stuff"></app-foo>
```

Let's call this new component `app-bar`. So the form above is changed to

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <app-bar formControlName="importantStuff"></app-bar>
</form>
```

For `app-bar` to work, it also needs to implements the `ControlValueAccessor` and needs to implement methods like `writeValue`, `updateValue`, etc. But my problem here is that this component is just a wrapper so in this case it needs to pass all the information back-and-forth between its parent/form and `app-foo`. Is there a way that I can connect `app-foo` with the form directly?

For example, I noticed that you have

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-bar',
    ...
    providers: [{
       provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
       useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppBarComponent),
       multi: true
    }]
})
```

Is it possible, for example, to replace `AppBarComponent` in the forwardRef directly to `AppFooComponent` somehow?

An other thing, suppose that `app-bar` also implements `ControlValueAccessor` and keeps everything in sync between `app-foo`. But this time the parent of `app-bar` does the following

```
this.form.controls.stuff.markAsTouched();
```

Is there a way for `app-bar` to get notified and then propagate this to `app-foo`.

Any help would be appreciated. Links to good tutorials are also very welcome!!

Comment: It is possible to do that, but as you have found, there is lots of work for no real gain. Another option is to look at ng-content, where you call <app-foo>bar content</app-foo> and place 'bar content' within an ng-content tag in your app.foo.html template.